# react-router only works for the root path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to route to multiple path using react router. But it only routes to the root path, not the others.

this is react code:

```
function Routing() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <App/>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path = "/" exact component={App} />
                    <Route path = "/home" exact component={Home} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </Router>   
    )
}
```

however, it gives me: Cannot GET /home

After researching on internet i saw multiple people had the same issue, one of the answer from stacoverflow to solve this was using this code on the server.

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.render('..build/index');
});
```

and:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
      res.render('..public/index');
    });
```

and:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
      res.render('index');
    });
```

but this gives me another error:

```
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
    at new View (/Users/mhkhan4/Desktop/Books2Go/backend/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:61:11)
    at Function.render (/Users/mhkhan4/Desktop/Books2Go/backend/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:570:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/mhkhan4/Desktop/Books2Go/backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
    at /Users/mhkhan4/Desktop/Books2Go/backend/server.js:17:7
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/mhkhan4/Desktop/Books2Go/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/mhkhan4/Desktop/Books2Go/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/mhkhan4/Desktop/Books2Go/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/mhkhan4/Desktop/Books2Go/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/mhkhan4/Desktop/Books2Go/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at param (/Users/mhkhan4/Desktop/Books2Go/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:354:14)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV=="production"){
    app.use(express.static("client/build"))
    const path=require('path')
    app.get("*",(req,res)=>{
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'client','build','index.html'))
    })
}
```

You have to provide the correct directory name and the middleware to be used.While you are sending static files you should mention it to be static